# Shopify liquid: Compare settings array with metafield value

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to find a solution for the following problem. I have a list of lenses with different powers. They are starting from -12.00 and going up to +8.00. For the most part, they are 0.50 apart from the next one (6.00, 6.50, 7.00 s.o.).
I have a list with all the possible powers stored under settings, in an array. And then for each available brand of lenses it has a metafield with the minimum available power and the maximum one.
I envisioned it as a comparison, display only the powers from settings that are between these limits. However, I hit a limitation. I can't store 6.5 for example in a metafield as a number, it can only be a string and it makes it hard to compare the settings value with this one.
I tried to use a math filter (times), but the number is rounded. If I have "6.5" and I use times filter, I get "6".

Questions:
1. How would you do this?
2. How can I make sure that each value, if it is not a string, have two decimal places? (e.g. 6.50)

Comment: Hi Andrew, I would like to talk to you about something VERY important.  Can you send an email to me at sachinkainth[at]hotmail.com please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the metafield is like this `product.metafields.power.value = 6.5`. Do this:

`{% assign power_value = product.metafields.power.value | plus: 0 %}`

Boom. `power_value` is now a number.

Comment: It will stop work as soon as you have a negative number there. If you have -6.5 and you apply that filter you will get -6.

Comment: Have a look at this - https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/math-filters

You can multiply/divide to some effect.